# JS regex for price

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for RegEx for Price, but couldn't find any full example.
I have this code:

```
var regex  = /^\d+(?:\.\d{3})$/;
var numStr = "10.044";
if ( regex.test(numStr) )
  {
    alert("Number is valid");
  }
else
  {
    alert("Number is NOT valid");
  }
```

But it needs to be improved:
dollar part should be 1-3 digits long and it should NOT start with '0'(like 01.548),
no other characters should be allowed in whole price, other than digits and '.'
there must be exactly 3 digits after '.'
zero values should not be allowed too, like 00.000

Comment: Should decimals be optional?

Comment: What about `1.100` or `1.110`?

Comment: Is `0.534` valid?

Comment: 1.100, 1.110 and 0.534 are valid prices

Comment: `/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)\.(?!000)([0-9]{3})$/` should do the trick.

Comment: So `1.000` is valid or invalid?

Comment: Can you add example and expected value?

Comment: What about just `2`?

Comment: Voting to close as "Needs details or clarity". There are far too many holes in your question which have prompted several unanswered questions. For future reference, you should be attentive to the comments.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 2 is invalid, as I said in question- 'there must be exactly 3 digits after '.' '

Comment: Yes, you said there must be three digits after a period but that doesn't mean that decimals are required as I asked in my first comment.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry, I guess must be != required

Comment: Well you only stated that three digits are required after the decimal. You did not state that the decimal itself is required. Much of your question's phrasing is ambiguous. Consider these two statements: `Three digits must follow the decimal if it exists` versus `A decimal is always required with three digits afterwards`. 5 different answers (2 deleted) have been posted and edited multiple times because of the ambiguities present in your question. I'm surprised it didn't get closed sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use negative lookahead checking if there are no one or more zeroes at the start followed by a digit 1-9 or that the whole match consists of only zeroes and dots.

```
^(?!0+[1-9]|[0.]+$)\d{1,3}\.\d{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D7bZUr/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?!0+[1-9]|[0.]+$)\d{1,3}\.\d{3}$/;
["01.548",
  "12",
  "0.0000",
  "12.000",
  "12.001",
  "1.100",
  "1.110",
  "0.534"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ": " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Comment: 12.000 should match

Comment: @Roland I see, I have updated the pattern.

Comment: nice, but 0.000 should not match

Comment: @Roland Ok, the update does not match that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0)\.(?!000)([0-9]{3})|([1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.000$` should do the trick.

- it starts with **0** or a **number 1-3 digits** that does not start with zero
- it ends with a **non-000** 3 digits number

OR

- it starts with a **number 1-3 digits** that does not start with zero
- it ends with **000**

Comment: According to a comment on another answer, "12.000 should match"

Answer (score 0):

What about non-regex solution?

```
function isValid(inputString) {
  var number=parseFloat(inputString);
  if(isNaN(number)) return false;
  if(number>=1000 || number<0) return false; // 1-3 digits of integer part
  var number1000=number*1000;
  if(number1000!=Math.floor(number1000) && number1000!=Math.ceil(number1000)) return false; // 1-3 digits of float part
  return true;
}
```